# Storyboard or xib with large number of view controllers

Tags: ios, testing, storyboard, tdd, xib

I have an app with a large number of view controllers (i estimate more then 70 VC) ill probably be building the app with iOS 10 deployment target my question is for this large number of VC are story board recommended or singe Xib file per class ill note that the app will be TDD driven and i need the code as modular as possible.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: So what is the issue?

Comment: Not an issue rather a recommendation which is better to use with the details ive provided.

Comment: it may help you http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/ce3669/difference-between-storyboard-and-xib/

Comment: 1st of all thanks for the link.
2nd of all i wanted a recommendation from developers who worked recently on projects with this large number of VC's in their projects what is their choice.

Comment: it depends on your project, what is the actual requirement. W/O it no body can  explain. An obviously link is helpful. First know difference b/w both things and compare to your project.

Comment: Thank you all for your help have a great  day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recently worked on an application with around 120-140 View controllers. We use both xib's and storyboards as the application is being developed from the time when storyboards were not introduced.

Using xib is considered to be obsolete but It's all up to you. If you want it to be test driven you can consider xib as a good option.

**The best thing you can do to keep it modular is to divide the whole project in modules and create different storyboards for each module. Try not to keep more than 10-12 screens in a single storyboard.**

Using storyboards with a large number of VC's could be cumbersome, as it reduces the flexibility, increases loading time, could be confusing and can considerably affect the development time.